# Why is the induced map on cofibers in the loop space homotopy pullback the counit?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Let $X$ be a space and consider the homotopy pullback diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Omega X @>>> *\\
@VVV @VVV \\
* @>>> X
\end{CD}$$

Taking the induced map on cofibers, we get a diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Omega X @>>> * @>>> \Sigma \Omega X\\
@VVV @VVV @VVfV\\
* @>>> X & @>>> X
\end{CD}$$

The map $f$ is the counit of the $\Sigma$-$\Omega$ adjunction. Is there a formal way to prove this (i.e. without factoring the map $\Omega X \to *$ explicitly as a cofibration followed by a weak equivalence)?

Comment: What you write is not quite true. The map $f$ is induced by a particular choice of homotopy for the the top which makes it a homotopy pullback. The choice $\Omega X\times I\ni(\ell,t)\mapsto\ell(t)\in X$ does the job and is quite canonical.

Comment: @merle How are you defining the counit for $\Sigma \dashv \Omega$? As the map coming from the the homotopy pushout of the homotopy pullback square?